# No permissions allowed even though the permissions granted

Tags: permissions, 7.1-nougat

I have an app on my Android 7.1 device. As you may see in the image;
app has no granted permissions even though I explicitly gave the WiFi permissions to this app.

I am sure some of the constitutional plugins used by this app requested the permissions.

Is there any way I can control the permissions I gave and possible revert them.

Let me know if you need more details.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by "WiFi permissions"? When a developer adds the ability to access Internet, it is automatically granted when you launch an app. Android does not ask for any explicit "WiFi permissions".

Comment: I think it is this one... <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

Comment: Is this an app that you've created yourself? If so you should read the Android developer docs on [protection levels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous), there are certain permissions that will not be asked for by the system and will be granted automatically. The "Permissions" section will show everything that you've given access to

Comment: Nope. This is not my app.

Comment: Can you clarify the question then? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Build tool will merge all Android project manifest files into a single manifest file called AndroidManifest.xml. I think if Android project has plugins with certain permission requests, these will popup at certain moment, but I don't know how to control the permissions of these plugins effectively.